# How to get the placeholder's value which is stored in a different file (same directory) using JSch exec

Tags: unix, ksh, jsch

With the conditions:

1. I cannot use any XML parser tool as I don't have permission , read only
2. My xmllint version does not support xpath, and I cannot update it , read only
3. I dont have xmlstarlet and cannot install it
4. I run my script using Java JSch exec channel ( I have to run it here )

So we have 3 files in a directory.

1. `sample.xml`
2. `values1.properties`
3. `values2.properties`

The contents of the files are as follows:

Sample.xml

```
<block>
 <name>Bob</name>
 <address>USA</address>
 <email>$BOB_EMAIL</email>
 <phone>1234567</phone>
</block>

<block>
 <name>Peter</name>
 <address>France</address>
 <cell>123123123</cell>
 <drinks>Coke</drinks>
 <car>$PETER_CAR</car>
 <bike>Mountain bike</bike>
</block>

<block>
 <name>George</name>
 <hobby>$GEORGE_HOBBY</hobby>
 <phone>$GEORGE_PHONE</phone>
</block>
```

values1.properties

```
JOE_EMAIL=joe@google.com
BOB_EMAIL=bob@hotshot.com
JACK_EMAIL=jack@jill.com
MARY_EMAIL=mary@rose.com
PETER_EMAIL=qwert1@abc.com
GEORGE_PHONE=Samsung
```

values2.properties

```
JOE_CAR=Honda
DAISY_CAR=Toyota
PETER_CAR=Mazda
TOM_CAR=Audi
BOB_CAR=Ferrari
GEORGE_HOBBY=Tennis
```

I use this script to get the xml block to be converted to a properties file format

```
NAME="Bob"
sed -n '/name>'${NAME}'/,/<\/block>/s/.*<\(.*\)>\(.*\)<.*/\1=\2/p' sample.xml
```

OUTPUT:

```
name=Bob
address=USA
email=$BOB_EMAIL
phone=1234567
```

How do I get the value of `$BOB_EMAIL` in `values1.properties` and `values2.properties`. Assuming that I do not know where it is located between the two (or probably more) properties file. Bacause it should work differently if I entered

```
Name=Peter
```

in the script, it should get

```
name=Peter
address=France
cell=123123123
drinks=Coke
car=$PETER_CAR
bike=Mountain bike
```

and the think that will be searched will be `PETER_CAR`

EXPECTED OUTPUT (The user only needs to input 1 Name at a time and the output expected is one set of data in properties format with the $PLACEHOLDER replaced with the value from the properties file):

User Input: `Name=Bob`

```
name=Bob
address=USA
email=bob@hotshot.com
phone=1234567
```

User Input: `Name=Peter`

```
name=Peter
address=France
cell=123123123
drinks=Coke
car=Mazda
bike=Mountain bike
```

Ultimately, the script that I need has this logic:

1. for every word with `$`
2. in the result of `sed -n '/name>'${name}'/,/<\/block>/s/.*<(.*)>(.*)<.*/\1=\2/p' sample.xml` ,
3. it will search for the value of that word in all of the properties file in that directory(or specified properties files),
4. then replace the word with `$` with the value found in the properties file

PARTIALLY WORKING ANSWER:

Walter A's answer is working in cmd line (putty) but not in Jsch exec.
I keep getting an error of `No value found for token 'var'` .

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211949/13792

Comment: How about `x=$(sed -n '/name>'${NAME}'/,/<\/block>/s/.*<\(.*\)>\(.*\)<.*/\1=\2/p' sample.xml); echo "$x"`

Comment: @Walter it still displayed the value with placeholder, the values that I need there are in the properties file

Comment: Your conditions are making it very difficult to perform your job.

Comment: @glennjackman what do I need to parse through properties files and look for the placeholders value?

Comment: It's the XML parsing part that requires an XML parser

Comment: @glenjackman I had a workaround with that. My problem now is how to populate the values of the placeholders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution beneath will look in the properties files a lot of times, so I think there is a faster solution for the problem.
The solution beneath will get you started and with small files you might be happy with it.

```
# Question has a bash en ksh tag, choose the shebang line you want
# Make sure it is the first line without space or ^M after it.
#!/bin/ksh
#!/bin/bash
# Remove next line (debugging) when all is working
# set -x
for name in Bob Peter; do
   sed -n '/name>'${name}'/,/<\/block>/s/.*<\(.*\)>\(.*\)<.*/\1=\2/p' sample.xml |
      while IFS="\$" read line var; do
         if [ -n "${var}" ]; then
            echo "${line}$(grep "^${var}=" values[12].properties | cut -d= -f2-)"
         else
            echo "${line}"
         fi
      done
   echo
done
```

EDIT: Commented two possible shebang lines, `set -x` and added output.

Result:

```
name=Bob
address=USA
email=bob@hotshot.com
phone=1234567

name=Peter
address=France
cell=123123123
drinks=Coke
car=Mazda
bike=Mountain bike
```

Comment: Im getting  No value found for token 'var'

Comment: can you explain to me where var is populated here?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. I tested it with bash but tried to use portable commands only. In the line `while IFS="\$" read line var` the variable var is filled when the line has a $ character or stays empty when there is no $. The next line should check the token. I will reverse the check (not -z but -n), maybe that helps.
Some info about checking empty variables: [checking vars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307503/whats-the-best-way-to-check-that-environment-variables-are-set-in-unix-shellscr).

Comment: -n did not work also. hmm . what is wrong . .  I execute the script using Jsch's exec channel.

Comment: Ahh. Jsch might do or omit other things.
1. Please test my script from the command-line. 2. You can add `#!/bin/ksh` or `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, that might overrule Jsch specific behaviour.

Comment: You might update your tags, I didn't know you wanted to call this using Java. When you already have a Java application, consider solving this in Java. A Java developer who needs to change your code will get really confused.

Comment: The #!/bin/ksh and #!/bin/bash did not do the trick. What is the difference when I execute this in cmd and in JSch exec? There were no issues since this one

Comment: The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) tries to force a kind of shell to execute this. It is ignored when the code is [sourced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326695/what-does-it-mean-to-source-a-file-in-unix-linux-context)

Comment: Try executing it from cmdline and see if it works there. I also added a `set -x` debugging option you can try when the cmdline also fails. The only reference to your errormessage I find with Google is [in some Java code](https://github.com/sqh4/debug/blob/master/NumberToken.java) so I think the script itself is working and your problem is how you look at the results in Java.

Comment: I tried running it in cmd. It returned everything and not just the values I need

Comment: No error with cmd, thats fine. It returned everything? Is that the `set -x` debug info? I show above my output, can you update the question if this is incorrect?

Comment: It is returning everything with a placeholder ($) . I am running it in a bigger directory with bigger files (I just simplified it with the question). But the problem here is that I only need the placeholder that is present in the output of the XML to properties format. (not all)

Comment: you have the best answer so far , only need a few more twicks

Comment: Then remove the two lines `else` and `echo "${line}"`

Comment: It is still returning more data than I need. Lets just say there are 1000 more blocks with different names and placeholders inside. So I just need the specific ones in which my `sed` script returns. You can check the "EXPECTED OUTPUT" section in my question.

Comment: With `for name in Bob Peter; ` I show data for Bob and Peter. I get the expected output for Bob, add an empty line and show the expected output for Peter. You can change it into `while read name` or `name=$1` when you want to enter the name differently.

Comment: It did not work, still displaying many data. Can you try making your xml file larger by placing new entries and placeholders? So you can replicate the one I am facing with the real files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81846/discussion-between-walter-a-and-philip-morris).

Answer (score 1):

```
. values1.properties
. values2.properties
sed -n '/name>'${NAME}'/,/<\/block>/s/.*<\(.*\)>\(.*\)<.*/echo \1="\2"/p' sample.xml >output
. output
```

Dangerous, and not the way I would prefer to do it.

Comment: Im getting Exit Code: 1

Comment: The . sources the file. Basically executes it in your current shell, which assigns all the variables.. ie PETER_EMAIL, etc. Your variables are then expanded when the output is sourced.

Comment: Im using JSch's exec channel to execute my script. Is this the problem?

Comment: I tried something like this first, but had problems with `bike=Mountain bike`. Additionally vars containing quotes will also be evaluated.

Comment: Sourcing was a cool way! But dangerous too... +1 since you have included the warning too..

Comment: $ -ksh: output: cannot create [Permission denied]

Answer (score 0):

A sed based version:

```
$ temp_properties=`mktemp`
$ NAME=Bob
$ sed '/./{s/^/s|$/;s/=/|/;s/$/|g/}' values*.properties > $temp_properties
$ sed -n '/name>'${NAME}'/,/<\/block>/s/.*<\(.*\)>\(.*\)<.*/\1=\2/p' sample.xml | sed -f $temp_properties
```

Gives:

```
name=Bob
address=USA
email=bob@hotshot.com
phone=1234567
```

It does have issues of script injection. However, if you trust the `values*.properties` files & contents of `NAME` variable, you are good to go.

Comment: Did you by any chance miss out any character in above snippet? These command run as-are on my system.

Comment: sed: file /tmp/tmp.YUHfVm4670 line 229: unterminated `s' command
 - Still getting this

Comment: Does your file have `crlf` line endings? check `file values*.properties`... If yes, you can change using `dos2unix filename`...

Comment: ^^ Does your file have `crlf` line endings? I could still have got alternate ways, if you had also answered that... :D

Comment: `sed '/./{s/\r//;s/^/s|$/;s/=/|/;s/$/|g/}' values*.properties > $temp_properties`

Comment: I see a normal properties file with key value pairs inside. no crlf line endings